# Perl: How to check what is being returned from a subroutine

Tags: perl, return-value, subroutine

I have a subroutine that will return two hashes when all goes well. But the sub checkouts output of command and if it matches a certain pattern, it returns with "-1".  Is there anyway to check the return of the subroutine from where I called it?

Kinda like:

```
if (RETURN_VALUE == -1){
   do something}
   else
   go as normal with the hashes
```

Comment: does it have to return -1? it may not be an option for you, but in general I've found it best for functions to either die on error (and be wrapped in an eval block) or just simply return nothing (i.e. `return;`).  Having to test for different types of response makes the code more awkward and fragile...

Comment: No, it doesn't have to be -1.  That is just what I have always used as my error code for a broad error.  When it drops out of the sub, if the output shows that error code, the foreach loop that is calling it goes to its next iteration.

Comment: This is a perfect example of why exception handling should not be dealt with using return codes. You should look at Exception::Class, Try::Tiny or TryCatch and add real exception handling to your program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You function should return references to the two hashes on success and nothing upon failure. Then you can just check the truth value of the function call.

```
sub myfunc {
    my %hash1;
    my %hash2;
    return (\%hash1, \%hash2);
}

my $ref1;
my $ref2;
unless (($ref1, $ref2) = myfunc()) { 
    print "Something went wrong\n";
} else { 
    print "OK\n";
}
```

Comment: You can write `unless (my ($ref1, $ref2) = … )` to tighten the scope.

Comment: I think I'm going to use this method.  
daxim: thanks for that clarification.  Makes it easier to edit if variable name needs changing.

Comment: @daxim I started with that as well, but thought one may want to keep the values beyond the error checking block.

Comment: @RzITex please mark the answer you choose as the 'accepted answer' by clicking on the check box outline to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 3):

How could one function return **two hashes**?

If you mean `hashrefs`, the check would be quite simple:

```
my ($h1,$h2) = myFunction();
if ( !ref($h1) || (ref($h1) ne "HASH"))
{
   die 'error';
}
```

Comment: a function can quite easily return two hashes (`return %hash1, %hash2;`) - of course as Alan Haggai Alavi says in his answer, the caller won't be able to separate them. this may or may not be a problem, depending on what the code is doing with them...

Comment: a function returns a list or a single var, the type is not used, its not C++ ....

Comment: i think that's being a bit pedantic - from the point of view of the developer it appears like hashes are being passed around: `sub myFunction { ... return %hash1, %hash2; };  my %foo = myFunction();`

Answer (score 0):

If you return two (or any number for that matter) hashes from a subroutine, the result will be a single hash. You will not be able to separate the original hashes from the result in a normal manner. Returning hash references will not exhibit this problem.

Suppose `foo()` returns two hash references when the pattern is matched and returns -1 when it does not match.

```
my ( $value_1, $value_2 ) = foo;

if ( $value_1 == -1 ) {
    # pattern did not match
}
else {  # for strict checks: elsif ( ref $value_1 eq 'HASH' && ref $value_2 eq 'HASH' ) {
    # pattern matched
}
```

Comment: A hash reference can be compared.